# Generate input button with onClick function using JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I use JavaScript to generate form input fields on my page. Everything works fine, except the button. I came across some problems generation the button's onClick function using DOM. You can see the code below, but on my page, there is no the onClick function as the attribute of the input button tag:

```
n = 1;
function generate() {
    var radiomore = document.createElement("input");
    radiomore.type = "button";
    radiomore.name = "opt[" + n + "]";
    radiomore.value = "Add more options";
    radiomore.setAttribute = ('onClick',addradiomore);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Op: " + radiomore.outerHTML + "<br/>";
    document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(div);
n++;
}

function addradiomore() {
    //here goes the function code
}
```

And this is what it generates on my page:

```
<input type="button" name="opt[1]" value="Add more options">
```

There is no function?!?!

P.S.
Even if I use like this it doesn't work:

```
radiomore.onclick = addradiomore();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
radiomore.onclick = addradiomore;
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/CM9dG/)

Comment: Yeah. The problem was it somehow doesn't show in button's attributes when you use inspect element. This code works, no matter there is no label of the function between input button tags. Thank you.

Comment: @CJRamki Thanks for confirming !

Comment: @user3244442 Additionally, you can view the event listeners attached in this way under the "Event Listeners" tab in the dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
radiomore.onclick = function () {
    addradiomore();
};
```

Comment: But how can I insert into my code. I know how to make a new function, but I need to make it in a dom like above.